# How to center image with full height and variable width

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-8, winjs

I'm trying to show an image (of arbitrary width/height) in full screen when the screen (also of arbitrary width/height). I'm using HTML/CSS/JS. I want the image to always take up the full screen. If the image is a lower aspect ratio than the screen then I should clip the top and bottom. If the image is a higher aspect ratio than the screen then I should clip the left and right. I never want to see black around the edges.
I can do it using background-image (and background-position, etc.) but I'm having an issue with that (the image flashes as I update it). So I'd like to use an  tag. Does anyone know how I'd do that?

Comment: What browsers do you want or need to support? What have you tried so far? Can you show some code? What are the problems with your current approach? Why do you need or want to do this? How come you would get "black around the edges"? Note that you can edit your question to add more details!

Comment: Windows 8, so it's IE10. No other browser compatibility necessary. If you can come up with an answer to the problem then I doubt it will duplicate anything I've thrown at it so far. I need/want to do this because it's the requirement. I'd get black around the edges if black were the background color and the image didn't take the whole screen.

Comment: Is this a window, or an app? E.g. Can it resize while running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question is nice and clear and obviously the OP doesn't have any code... that's why he's asking the question.

I've run into that exact issue before. I don't think there's a way to do it using HTML/CSS if you want the image to end up larger than the containing element with the excess clipped unless you can put the image in the background. If you need to use the  tag as you state, then a good solution is to do this imperatively. Here's what I did.

```
function setImagePosition() {
    var img = q(".viewCamera #viewport img");
    if (outerWidth/outerHeight > img.naturalWidth/img.naturalHeight) {
        img.style.width = format("{0}px", outerWidth);
        img.style.height = "";
        img.style.top = format("{0}px", (outerHeight - img.clientHeight) / 2);
        img.style.left = "0px";
    } else {
        img.style.width = "";
        img.style.height = format("{0}px", outerHeight);
        img.style.top = "0px";
        img.style.left = format("{0}px", (outerWidth - img.clientWidth) / 2);
    }
}
```

Let me explain...

The `outerWidth/outerHeight` results in the aspect ratio of the window. The `img.naturalWidth/img.naturalHeight` is the aspect ratio of the image. If the first is greater then we need to set the width of the image to the width of the window and calculate the `top` value to center the image vertically. If the second is greater then we need to set the height of the image and then use the `left` to center the image horizontally.

Hope that helps! You can find a bunch of Windows 8 HTML/JS related help in my codeSHOW project at [codeshow.codeplex.com](http://codeshow.codeplex.com) and in the Windows Store at [aka.ms/codeshowapp](http://aka.ms/codeshowapp).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, have a look at these:
http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

or more lightweight:
http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Comment: No jQuery. I want to do it in pure HTML/CSS.

Answer (score -1):

if you want it to stretch use background-size, or if it has to be a tag, use max-width:100%; in order to center use display:block; and margin:0 auto;

Im not quite sure what youre after though...

How do you update the image so it flashes? When does it occure? It sounds like a job for background-position:center.

Comment: how about providing some code? sorry but with the unlegible question provided and no code i doubt anyone will be able to understand and help you